# What does the => operator do in C#?

Tags: c#, lambda

I’ve been encountering code examples and using them in my own code for a while now without knowing that it is the lambda operator. You’d think doing a  search in Google or Bing like:

c# "=>"

would give you literal examples of code containing that operator and some clue to its name. But no such luck.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+lamda+expression&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: Is there a question here, aside from in the subject line?

Comment: @Adam Robinson: Nope. Just an explanation that finding information about this operator is a problem. Then I answered it and (hopefully) have gotten it into a wiki entry and (more hopefully) will help someone else out...and that is the point, after all.

Comment: @RQDQ: Thanks, but that's an after-the-fact answer if you don't already know the term and all you have to go on is characters occurring in code.

Comment: @Stonetip, well - when I got here the title of the question was "What is a lambda expression".

Comment: @RQDQ, you're quite right and I realized my mistake. Hey, I'm just so excited to finally know what the d*** things are called.

Answer (score 2):

By random chance, rolling over some code in Visual Studio with ReSharper installed, I learned what they are. Now I can join the Lambda Lambda Lambda fraternity (see Revenge of the Nerds)!

[Lambda Expressions (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) has more information on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

A Google search for "lambda expression" will get you here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

> A lambda expression is an anonymous function that can contain expressions and statements, and can be used to create delegates or expression tree types.

Comment: The problem is seeing the operator ( => ) in various code examples and not knowing what it's called. I even tried using Google Code Search, e.g. http://www.google.com/codesearch?hl=en&lr=&q=%3D%3E&sbtn=Search and that brings up code, but seems kind of random. It certainly didn't help explain what the operator means or how the expressions work.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't pick up on that because your headline originally said something like "what's a lambda expression?"

Answer (score 0):

lambdas are shorthand for little self contained functions.

```
delegate string StringModifier(string data);

public void Test()
{
    StringModifier removeQuotes = (data) => data.Replace("\"", "");
    string blah = "testotest\"testeste";
    string bluh = removeQuotes(blah); // returns "testotesttesteste";
}
```